# Xamarin in Visual Studio cannot add xamarin.forms from Nuget

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2012, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I downloaded the xamarin.form project from github. But when I build the project it is missing the xamarin.forms package.

I tried adding it with Nuget but got this error:

```
Installing 'Xamarin.Forms 1.3.3.6323'.
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.Forms 1.3.3.6323'.
Adding 'Xamarin.Forms 1.3.3.6323' to DialogPro.
Uninstalling 'Xamarin.Forms 1.3.3.6323'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Xamarin.Forms 1.3.3.6323'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'Xamarin.Forms 1.3.3.6323'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-    net45+sl50+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.##
```

How can it fix it? Please help me! Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the Github project you are trying to build? By the looks of it you are trying to add a reference to a project that is not one of its targets

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are targeting the wrong profile. You don't have windows phone but you do have silverlight. Do you need silverlight? I know that it definitely works with Profile 78 or 259. Adjust your targets and then try to add the nuget package again. Unfortunately, this means you probably should re-add all of your nugets for that package since the target changed.

***edit***:
Here's a good article on some of the xamarin supported profiles: http://danrigby.com/2014/04/16/xamarin-pcl-profile-notes/. I forgot that silver light is included. If you open the project in Xamarin Studio, it actually tells you the profile number. Open the csproj in a text editor and see if the profile number is listed at the top.

Comment: Thanks @valdetero  Silverlight is automatic choose by xamarin, i can't remove it.
what is profile 78 or 256, how to config my project.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are adding Xamarin.Forms to a project that doesn't target any of the required frameworks.

You only need to add Xamarin forms package to your android, iOS, WinPhone and PCL projects.